# Why isn't my Linked List printing out the correct numbers?

Tags: python, class, linked-list, nodes

I am making a Linked List that should include 3 nodes with data 1, 2, and 3. And it should print out their data which is 1, 2, and 3. But, every time I run it, it gives me a 1. Why is that? I am new to python please help

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def printlist(self):
        temp = self.head
        while(temp):
            print(temp.data)
            temp = temp.next


node1 = LinkedList()
node1.head = Node(1)
node2 = Node(2)
node3 = Node(3)

node1.next = node2
node2.next = node3

node1.printlist()

#THIS WILL PRINT: 1 instead of 1 2 3
```

Comment: Poor choice of name for your linked list: `node1`. It's not a node. You've accidentally failed to connect Node(1) to Node(2). Instead you've connected the linked list to Node(2).

Comment: You're using `node1` as both a linked list and a node, and confusing yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`node1` is a `LinkedList` instance, not a `Node` instance. Its `head` is a `Node`. You need to set the `head`'s `next` attribute to point to `node2` in order for them to be linked together.

To do so, change the line

```
node1.next = node2
```

to

```
node1.head.next = node2
```

You might want to change your variable names in order to avoid confusing `Node`s and `LinkedList`s. Here's my suggestion:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def printlist(self):
        temp = self.head
        while(temp):
            print(temp.data)
            temp = temp.next


my_list = LinkedList()
node1 = Node(1)
node2 = Node(2)
node3 = Node(3)

my_list.head = node1
node1.next = node2
node2.next = node3

my_list.printlist()

# output:
# 1
# 2
# 3
```